# How to find & populate the 3rd highest Amount & populate the same 3rd highest amount into New Column (Cut_of_3)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How to find & populate the 3rd highest Amount & populate the same 3rd highest Amount into Cut_of_3 (new col) and repeat the same into that related ID, if there is no 3rd highest Amount for that ID, need to populate the 100 into that Related ID. Pls find sample dataset & Expecting result. Thanks in Advance.!

Sample Dataset:-

```
ID  Status       Date      Amount
1   New         01/05/20    20
1   Assigned    02/05/20    30
1   In-Progress 02/05/20    50
2   New         02/05/20    30
2   Removed     03/05/20    20
3   New         09/05/20    50
3   Assigned    09/05/20    20
3   In-Progress 10/05/20    30
3   Closed      10/05/20    10
4   New         10/05/20    20
4   Assigned    10/05/20    30
```

Expecting Result:-

```
ID  Status       Date      Amount  Cut_of_3
1   New         01/05/20    20        20
1   Assigned    02/05/20    30        20
1   In-Progress 02/05/20    50        20
2   New         02/05/20    30        100
2   Removed     03/05/20    20        100
3   New         09/05/20    50        35
3   Assigned    09/05/20    35        35
3   In-Progress 10/05/20    40        35
3   Closed      10/05/20    10        35
4   New         10/05/20    20        100
4   Assigned    10/05/20    30        100
```

Comment: How do you get the 35 in Amount in output, what is the logic behind it. What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can achieve with use of `Window` functions

```
val window = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("ID")

// collect as list and sort descending and get the third value 
df.withColumn("Cut_of_3", sort_array(collect_list($"Amount").over(window), false)(2))
  // if if there is no third value it returns null and replace null with 100
  .na.fill(100, Seq("Cut_of_3"))
  .sort("ID")
  .show(false)
```

Output:

```
+---+-----------+--------+------+--------+
|ID |Status     |Date    |Amount|Cut_of_3|
+---+-----------+--------+------+--------+
|1  |New        |01/05/20|20    |20      |
|1  |Assigned   |02/05/20|30    |20      |
|1  |In-Progress|02/05/20|50    |20      |
|2  |New        |02/05/20|30    |100     |
|2  |Removed    |03/05/20|20    |100     |
|3  |New        |09/05/20|50    |20      |
|3  |Assigned   |09/05/20|20    |20      |
|3  |In-Progress|10/05/20|30    |20      |
|3  |Closed     |10/05/20|10    |20      |
|4  |New        |10/05/20|20    |100     |
|4  |Assigned   |10/05/20|30    |100     |
+---+-----------+--------+------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks Koiralo, Here how you find the 3rd highest for 1st ID "1" and same similar to ID "3". It's a condition like that, probably some workaround like, find the rank dense based on partition by ID and Make a alias join with the main df.